# Magento 2 products backend, product title in list not the same as what is in product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3

When I load the magento backend, the product title does not reflect the title that is in the actual product.
For example, the product might say, "New jewelry ring set" and but in the actual product (when I go in and edit the product) I have changed it to something different, i.e. "Jewellery Set - New In Box - Free Shipping".

So the product's actual title and what is shown in the search, both backend and front end are not changing to what I changed it to.

It just stays the same as what it was.
I tried clearing the cache, restarting the indexers, reindexing, restarting the VPS server container, etc. but nothing seems to work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the

> Catalog->product->edit

check your store means are changing in your default store?

and other store have default store value or not